# how to determine ajax attribute

Tags: ajax, attributes

var ID = $(this).attr("id");

"id" is the attribute as defined by w3schools - $(selector).attr(attribute)

I am new to ajax and would like to know where and how this attribute is defined

Comment: id is defined the unique identity in your page..what about ajax????

Comment: whats this unique identity you are speaking of? this id im utilising is retrieved from a datbase

Comment: $(this).attr("id") here id is the id of selector

Comment: Ng, this ID is not related to a database. It's referring to the html "id" attribute. It's possible that you might generate html elements that correspond to items in a database and you might give them id attributes that somehow relate to the database ids, but you'll have to provide us more information related to your particular project and goals if you want us to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class='user' type="text" id="username" value='test' />
```

Now in Ajax

```
var name = $('#username').val() // gives you 'test'
```

attr give the value of attribute , like user for class and username for id and test for value
Use:

```
var dom_cls = $(this).attr("class") // user
var dom_id= $(this).attr("id") //username
var dom_value= $(this).val() //test
```

read here for more 
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you are using some syntax which is not native HTML or Javascript. Are you referring to a framework such as jQuery?

To give you an example of how the "id" attribute is defined, check out the following html:

```
<div id="banana" onclick="alert( $(this).attr("id") )">Click Me</div>
```

When you click on the "Click Me" text, that would show an alert box with the message "banana", because that is the "id" assigned to the .

The object "this" refers to the object that received the event--the div in this case. And the jQuery function $(this) produces a jQuery object that has methods such as "attr" etc. The attr method simply retrieves the value of the specified attribute for the selected object--in this case it is the "id" attribute on the div, but you can use it to query any attribute.

Here's another example:

```
<input id="txt_name" name="username" onchange="update();">
<script>
  function update() 
  {
     var x = $('#txt_name').attr("name");
     alert(x);
  }
</script>
```

That would show an alert with the message "username" when you type in the textbox. It is using the jQuery selector to get the element with the id "txt_name", which is the textbox, and then it is using the attr method to get the value of the "name" attribute, which is "username".
Hope this helps clarify things for you. If not, post a link to the w3schools page you are looking at.

Comment: i am attempting to retrieve a variable called keywords to be inputted into ajax so as to allow me to link this variable to another file. THe ajax is mandatory for me to proceed with my functions

Comment: Where does the keywords variable come from? Is it from the page's meta tag? Or is it in the querystring? Or is it a script variable?
Can you explain more about your setup. You talk about "ajax" like its something used for input and output. But it's really a general concept about javascript and asynchronous http requests working together to provide a better user interface experience. So instead of saying "ajax", try to refer to the exact tasks you are trying to achive, such as retrieving database results from a server-side api call etc.

Comment: this keyword variable is retrieved from a previous page by adopting $_GET['keywords'], so basically i need to assign this to a variable in ajax to be directed to another page.
 var ID = $(this).attr("id"), this has been applied and is working seamlessly for another variable which i have no issue with. I need another var keyword which i have difficulties defining it. Thanks for spending time on this and i apologise for the vague questions